# Null Pointer Exception when trying to populate a list view with a custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I'm having a problem when trying to populate a list view with a custom adapter. I have an array of Restaurant objects stored in an ArrayList and those objects are then passed into the ArrayAdapter. I have checked the contents of the ArrayAdapter and it does contain the objects I have passed in. However the problem I seem to be having is that when list.setAdapter(adapter) is called it throws an exception.

The Following code shows how I try to populate the ListView

```
private void populateListView() {
    ArrayAdapter<Restaurants> adapter = new RestaurantsAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.restaurantListView);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This is my custom adapter. It is an inner class of the activity that is trying to display the list.

```
    private class RestaurantsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Restaurants> {

    public RestaurantsAdapter() {
        super(RestaurantsList.this,R.layout.layout_of_list_view,restaurants);
        //restaurants is an object array that is filled in the outer class
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
        //this makes sure we have a view to work with
        View v = convertView;

        if(v == null) //create new view
        {
            v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_of_list_view, parent, false);
        }

        //populate the list

        Restaurants r = restaurants.get(position);

        TextView restName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.restaurantName);
        restName.setText(r.getName());

        TextView desc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.restaurantDescription);
        desc.setText(r.getLocation());

        return v;
    }
}
```

And this is the XML file that describes how each item in the ListView should be displayed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/restaurantImage"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/restaurantName"
    android:layout_marginLeft="89dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:text="Description"
    android:id="@+id/restaurantDescription"
    android:layout_marginLeft="89dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"/>
```

While this is the XML file that contains the ListView itself.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="false">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/restaurantListView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The following error is displayed in the logcat when the code is ran.

```
12-16 17:30:38.360    1839-1839/project.b_ourguest.bourguest W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
12-16 17:30:38.360    1839-1839/project.b_ourguest.bourguest W/System.err﹕ at project.b_ourguest.bourguest.RestaurantsList.populateListView(RestaurantsList.java:90)
12-16 17:30:38.360    1839-1839/project.b_ourguest.bourguest W/System.err﹕ at project.b_ourguest.bourguest.RestaurantsList.access$000(RestaurantsList.java:25)
12-16 17:30:38.360    1839-1839/project.b_ourguest.bourguest W/System.err﹕ at project.b_ourguest.bourguest.RestaurantsList$1.run(RestaurantsList.java:54)
12-16 17:30:38.360    1839-1839/project.b_ourguest.bourguest W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-16 17:30:38.360    1839-1839/project.b_ourguest.bourguest W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-16 17:30:38.360    1839-1839/project.b_ourguest.bourguest W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-16 17:30:38.360    1839-1839/project.b_ourguest.bourguest W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-16 17:30:38.360    1839-1839/project.b_ourguest.bourguest W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 17:30:38.360    1839-1839/project.b_ourguest.bourguest W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-16 17:30:38.360    1839-1839/project.b_ourguest.bourguest W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-16 17:30:38.360    1839-1839/project.b_ourguest.bourguest W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-16 17:30:38.360    1839-1839/project.b_ourguest.bourguest W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I think the problem is not in the posted code.

Comment: I'm not quite sure where else it could be. Any suggestions?

Comment: RestaurantsList is the activity class I am working in. The code "RestaurantsList.class" is referring to the context.

Comment: what is at line 90 in RestaurantsList.java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Comment
```

I think you need to call this code:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.restaurantListView);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

in your onActivityCreated() method for a fragment or on your onCreate() method for an Activtiy, after you have called your layout.xml file.

Comment: The problem was that I was setting the content view after populating the list view. By simply setting the content view before populating the list view, it solved the error. Thank you.